# How to put items of sublists back to back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, join

I am working on a project called "Print Table" from 'Automate The Boring Stuff with Python' book. And I struggled to print every sublist side by side. Here is the list of items after I equalized characther numbers:

`newtable = [['  apples', ' oranges', 'cherries', '  banana'], ['Alice', '  Bob', 'Carol', 'David'], [' dogs', ' cats', 'moose', 'goose']]`

Here is how it should look in the end:

```
  apples Alice dogs
 oranges Bob   cats
cherries Carol moose
  banana David goose
```

And here is how I handled it in dumbest way possible:

```
for x in newtable:
    xi = newtable.index(x)
    for y in x:
        yi = newtable[xi].index(y)
        for z in newtable:
            zi = newtable.index(z)
            print(newtable[zi][yi],end=" ")
        print("\n")
    break
```

It works but i want to find out how can i make it with less headaches. How could i make it with .join() or sth. else?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`zip` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function to produce the expected outcome.

```
>>> for row in zip(*newtable):
...     print(*row)
...
  apples Alice  dogs
 oranges   Bob  cats
cherries Carol moose
  banana David goose
```